# Printing results immediately (php)

Tags: php

I have a php script that connects 10 different servers to get data. I want it to print the results of the 1st connection before the second one begins.

Comment: Please elaborate and give an example of the code you are using

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) and/or [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php), you should get what you want.

Here is a quick demonstration :

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<10 ; $i++) {
    echo "$i<br />";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Each second, a number will be sent to the browser, without waiting for the loop/script to end.

*(Without both flush and `ob_flush`, it waits until the end of the script to send the output)*

Explanation about why you need both, quoting from the flush page in the manual :

> Flushes the write buffers of PHP and
>   whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a
>   web server, etc). This attempts to
>   push current output all the way to the
>   browser with a few caveats.
>
> flush() may not be able to override
>   the buffering scheme of your web
>   server and it has no effect on any
>   client-side buffering in the browser.
>   It also doesn't affect PHP's userspace
>   output buffering mechanism. This means
>   you will have to call both ob_flush()
>   and flush() to flush the ob output
>   buffers if you are using those.

*If this doesn't work for you, taking a look at the comments on the two pages of the manual can give you a couple of pointers on "why it could fail"*

Comment: @sshow : I've heard this question asked a couple of times by colleagues, at work, actually -- and used it myself once or twice -- that helps ^^

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

**ob_end_flush**
http://us.php.net/ob_end_flush

This function empties the output buffer and disables output buffering.  Everything after this function is send to the browser immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, ob_flush should do it. I do this all the time with a LOOONG page, when I want to watch the progress of the operation.